# How do I change the prompt in zsh?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2

I have iTerm (with zsh) and it looks like:
[image]

And when I tap <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image]

I want pin info about battery on the top of terminal, is it possible?

Comment: This isn't "pinned to the top of your terminal" it is a complicated zsh shell prompt string which is why it appears before each command line.

Comment: Probably, it was necessary to ask the question differently. I want to pin one line on the top, but I don't know how.

Comment: You probably want to remove the battery indicator from `PS1` and put it in `RPS1` instead, along with some ANSI escape codes in `RPS1` to position the cursor before displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to pin a [battery indicator](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-battery). Tmux is not part of Zsh or iTerm, but a pretty light-weight tool that is also useful for other things like window/pane management.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with **tmux**:

1. Install  `brew install tmux`
2. Add to ~/.tmux.conf: `set -g status-position top`
3. Load config: `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`
4. Run `tmux`

Now you can add any information to top line using tmux config.